# Can't add something after second image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out how to add html after the second image on a page.
My code is working fine if I target `<p>`, `<div>` or whatever, but not images.

I don't get any error in console.

Here my JS :
`$("#blog-main > img:nth-child(2)").append("<div>inserted div</div>");`

And html is like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-8 blog-main" id="blog-main">
<p></p>
<img src="" />
<p></p>
<img src="" />
</div>
```

Can someone help me on this one ? Solution must be really simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you need to target _every_ second image in the div or just _the_ second image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`:eq(1)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** to select second img tag and use **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** to add content after the img tag

```js
 $("#blog-main > img:eq(1)").after("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8 blog-main" id="blog-main">
  <p></p>
  <img src="" />
  <p></p>
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks, but only after adding another ">" like this $("#blog-main >> img:eq(1)"). No idea why

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-child()` looks for all elements inside `#blog-main`, not only for `img`. Use `:eq()` instead:

```
$("#blog-main > img:eq(1)").append("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

Update. Yes, I forgot that you need to add element **after** `<img>`, not into it, so it should be, for example, `.after()` instead of `.append()`:

```
$("#blog-main > img:eq(1)").after("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0ym54zo/).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to using `:eq()`, you can also use `:nth-of-type()`:

```
$("#blog-main > img:nth-of-type(2)").append("<div>inserted div</div>");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2kx87xx/)